# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have made a form validation using ajax post method. But i got the error "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null**"...Can anybody help me to solve this...?

**My Code**

```
$.post("register.php",{uname:uname,pwd:pwd,cfmpwd:cfmpwd,email:email,gender:gender}).success(function(data){


        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('.chatregalert').fadeIn('slow');
        if(obj.success == 1){
            $('.chatregalert').css('color','#067800');
            $('.chatuname').val('');
            $('.chatpwd').val('');
            $('.chatcfmpwd').val('');
            $('.chatemail').val('');
            $('.chatgender').val('');
        }else{
            $('.chatregalert').css('color','#CC0000');
        }
        $('.chatregalert').html(obj.msg);


    });
    return false;
});
```

I have tried alert(data) for success...It alert an empty box... How can i fix this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution. The problem is my server doesn't  support JSON because the version of my PHP is **5.1.6**. The JSON support available only **PHP 5.2 and higher** versions..

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to do it like this :

```
$.post("register.php",
       {uname:uname,pwd:pwd,cfmpwd:cfmpwd,email:email,gender:gender},
       function(data){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $('.chatregalert').fadeIn('slow');
            if(obj.success == 1){
                $('.chatregalert').css('color','#067800');
                $('.chatuname').val('');
                $('.chatpwd').val('');
                $('.chatcfmpwd').val('');
                $('.chatemail').val('');
                $('.chatgender').val('');
            }else{
                $('.chatregalert').css('color','#CC0000');
            }
            $('.chatregalert').html(obj.msg);
     });
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have issues with your php script? Did you try to call it manually without ajax and if it works, try to just return parameters values to be sure you receive good data.

Comment: The same code works fine in local XAMPP server.. but it doesn't works in online server.. I think the server doesn't response the json object.. Because when i changed the code as....... .success(function(data){ alert(data) });... it alerts an empty box.. the server returns null..